# Parameter is not valid when Reading an image from S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, memorystream

I am getting `parameter is not valid` error when trying to convert stream to image.

I my C# ASP.NET application, I upload an image to Amazon S3 and download it again for manipulation.

I've checked that the uploaded image is ok by viewing it online on S3.

**I am downloading the image using this code:**

```
 using (AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey))
{
   GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
   {
      BucketName = "mybucket",
      Key = "temp/" + sp.FileGuid + Path.GetExtension(sp.FileName)
   };

    using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request)) // S3Response
   {

     using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
            int file_size_in_bytes = Convert.ToInt32(response.Headers.GetValues("Content-Length")[0]);
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[file_size_in_bytes];
            int numBytesToRead = file_size_in_bytes;

           int read;
           while ((read = response.ResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
           {
             memStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

   response.ResponseStream.Close();

    ...
```

I convert the response stream of the image to byte array in order to pass it to WCF service for later manipulation.

In the WCF I do (partial code):

```
  using (Stream filestream = new MemoryStream(sp.ImageFile)
  {

     **// GET THE ERROR IN THIS LINE!**
     System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(filestream);
  }
```

`sp.ImageFile` holds the convert response stream to byte array.

I read the byte array into a stream and create the image again from the stream. In the code above you can see where I get the `parameter is not valid error`.

I assume that in some place the conversion of the stream data of the image to either byte array or stream masses up the image data, so it created a corrupted image data, but I am not sure.

Spend all day trying to solve this without success. The only way it worked is when I directly pass the uploaded file stream to the System.Drawing.FromStream, but that's not what I want to do.

Really Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this may help. If the stream is not positioned at the begining the image may not load.

```
  using (Stream filestream = new MemoryStream(sp.ImageFile)
  {
     var checkSeek = filestream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

     **// GET THE ERROR IN THIS LINE!**
     System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(filestream);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, did it, same exception